# Blending 2 dimensions and 2 metrics into 1 dimension and 1 metric

Tags: google-analytics, looker-studio

I have a UA account and a GA4 account.

In UA I have:
Dimension: Event Category
Metric: Unique Events

In GA4:
Dimension: Event name
Metric: Event count

Is there a way to blend data in a way that I have 1 dimension (event category OR event name) and 1 metric (unique events OR event count)

I'd really need to come to 1 single dimension and 1 single metric.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data studio supports blending data which means to join two or more datasets. Here you ased for appending data which is in SQL called an UNION ALL.

**How to union two dataset in Data Studio**

First generate a Google Sheet document with the numbers 0 and 1:
[image]

Add this sheet to Data Studio and take care that the column is interpreted as a number:
[image]

To each of your datasets from UA and GA4 please add a calculated field `dummy` with
the formula `0` and in the 2nd datset with the formula `1`.
Blend these dataset together:
[image]

Since the column `test` on the left dataset has the value 0 and 1, the other two datasets are unioned.

To combine the two dimensions, please add the `+` twice:
[image]
and enter following formula there

```
case when test=0 then name else name2 end
```

and a formula for the metric (`counts` and `events` columns) as well:

```
case when test=0 then counts else events end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than Blending, if you want to "**UNION**" two separate tables, currently the Google Data Studio does not support it, however I recommend you to use this tool called Windsor AI, This platform will allow you to see all different kinds of Data Sources and do whatever operations you want with them in one place.

Suppose, I want data from Google Analytics, I'll simply choose the data source from the account I want to pull the Data from..

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btDyi.png)

From there you can preview your Data and then procced to pull it and from Multiple Tables like here

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecXEO.png)

You can then export it to any Data Platform you want

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B27Vh.png)

Hope this Helps..
P.S. This is a genuine problem that Data Studio has, although Data Studio is relatively new, it lacks a lot of features that can enable it to be a viable platform amongst it's competitors.